# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '@noescape (Int?) throws -> Bool'

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I am wanting to check to see if the `smallestArr` contains -1, and if it contains at least one -1, call placeBlocks. I need to keep calling placeBlocks until the array fills up meaning they lost the game.

The error I receive is

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type
>   '@noescape (Int?) throws -> Bool'

```
var smallestArr = [Int?](count: 25, repeatedValue: -1)

while smallestArr.contains(-1){
    placeBlocks()
}
```

Comment: If you have an array of *optional* ints then the same solution as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34427936/1187415 to your previous question applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `[Int?]` to `[Int]` (non-optional array members)

```
var smallestArr = [Int](count: 25, repeatedValue: -1)
while (smallestArr.contains(-1)) {
    placeBlocks()
}
```

Note that karthik:s answer from SO thread [How do you check an array to see if it contains a nil value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427759/how-do-you-check-an-array-to-see-if-it-contains-a-nil-value/34427936#34427936) advised you to switch to using `-1` instead of `nil` as "non-assignment". If you use that method, there is no reason for `smallestArr` to be optional: use `[Int]` rather than `[Int?]`.

Off-topic: note also that in its current form, this closure might end up as an infinite loop (so perhaps `smallestArr` should be passed to peaceBlocks to possibly flip `-1` entries to other values?).

Comment: With an `[Int]` array, `smallestArr.contains(-1)` would work as well.

Comment: @MartinR You are right, must've made some mistake when I tried that in my playground (I thought it strange as I faulty verified 12 mins ago that this was not the case!). Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR Someone posted an answer just while I was writing mine, that was spot on (but then removed?), however due to my faulty playground venture I thought the one I was writing differed. Was it you? In such case I'll delete this one and you can undelete yours.

Comment: @MartinR Ok. Oh well, I'll leave for sleep then. Thanks again for your remark.